# Semicolons make deconstruction assignment problematic in Chrome Javascript Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, syntax-error

I ran the following code in turn in Chrome Javascript Console

```
{f}={f:3} // it created a new variable f with a value of 3
```

```
{f}={f:3}; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
```

```
{f}={f:3} // There is a blank line on it，error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
```

Why do they behave differently?

What I really want to ask is why the bad code run without error
in the first case.

The problem extends from here: [object_destructuring - Assignment separate from declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

Comment: Browser consoles are not a good way to do JavaScript experimentation before you understand how they operate.

Comment: *Especially* not the Chrome console as it tries to add some magic to what you wrote thus giving you mixed results. Like you see by adding `;` - that gives you the *correct* behaviour for the code you had. Chrome was just trying to be helpful and it *lied* to you about what the first piece of code would result in.